# how to get origins of UIImage in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to get the origin of image added in a subview but it always returns 0.0
here is the code

```
img.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 60)
mySubview.addSubview(img)

printIn("x origin of image is \(img.frame.origin.x)")
```

what is the correct code to get the origin of object in subview?
it works when i try to get the origin of subview **(mySubview.frame.origin.x)**

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot for this.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iRb45Qx.png image type is png

Comment: Looks like you're trying to print the origin before setting it.

Comment: We're asking about `img`. It cannot be an image; an image has no frame. It must be some kind _view_, since it has a frame. For example, perhaps it is a UIImageView. Is it?

Comment: yes matt it is UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the origin before setting the frame for the imageview.